# Python-based Discord Bot working locally but not once hosted on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, bots, discord, discord.py

I've created a discord bot that runs perfectly when launched locally, but won't answer to any command apart from !help once hosted and launched.
I got the error logs, here they are :

Trying to !kick @user :

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: user_kick is a required argument that is missing
```

The command works perfectly offline.

kick command is written like this :

```
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, user_kick : discord.Member):
  role = discord.utils.get(user_kick.guild.roles, name=config['perm_role'])
  if role in ctx.message.author.roles:
    await user_kick.kick(reason=None)
  else:
    await ctx.send(content="Permission denied!")
```

I have (I think ?) correct requirements.txt, runtime.txt and Procfile files.

Edit :

My requirements.txt file looks like this :

```
-e git+git://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py.git@async#egg=discord
```

Is there anything to change there ?
Thanks for reading me, and sorry if this is not the correct way to ask questions here.

EDIT 2:

Still no idea of why this is happening.

Comment: no links please, try to post a minimal, viable, reproducible example, we are not going to take a look through your repository

Comment: Edited my post with explanation of the kick command instead of the whole git

Comment: heroku automatic sleeping?

Comment: I'm certain the worker Dyno is activated, since the bot is only and responds to the help command.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a common problem like this with some of my bots. If your bot uses `on_message` then it will interfere with other commands.

To fix this, add `await client.process_commands(message)` somewhere in `on_message`. If you are not using `on_message`, then I suggest you check the requirements.txt one more time.

Example:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("!thecommand"):
                    #whatever you had in the command


    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: I'm not using on_message at all, so I'm going to look for something in requirements.txt.

Comment: what are you using? What is in your requirements.txt?

Comment: My requirements.txt is in the post